# JavaScript mouseover event vs click event

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program to draw paths on google map. I want the paths to change color and stroke size on `mouseover` and revert to the original state on `mouseout` (hot hovering).  This is working fine. I also want to change the color of the path to different color when the path is click. This is where the problem lies. The color changes but it revert back to its original color once I take the mouse pointer away from the path.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(actualPath, 'mouseover', function (event) {
    actualPath.setOptions({
        strokeColor: "#00FF00",//color on mouseover
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 6
    });
});

google.maps.event.addListener(actualPath, 'mouseout', function (event) {
    actualPath.setOptions({
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",//original color
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });
});

google.maps.event.addListener(actualPath, 'click', function (event) {
    actualPath.setOptions({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",//color I want to set on on click
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the new color (which you get by clicking) somewhere else and recall it when the mouse is out.

```
var pathColor = "#0000FF";

google.maps.event.addListener(actualPath, 'click', function (event) {
    actualPath.setOptions({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000"
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });

    pathColor = "#FF0000"

});
```

Now in the mouseout

```
google.maps.event.addListener(actualPath, 'mouseout', function (event) {
    actualPath.setOptions({
        strokeColor: pathColor
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });
});
```

Comment: How will this work (if required) with a second path?

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected result. Your click event works, but when you move your mouse away the "mouseout" event also triggered.

You should check if you clicked the path with a boolean value.

```
pathClicked = false;

google.maps.event.addListener(actualPath, 'click', function (event) {
actualPath.setOptions({
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",//color I want to set on on click
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3
});
pathClicked = true;
});


google.maps.event.addListener(actualPath, 'mouseout', function (event) {
if(!pathClicked){
actualPath.setOptions({
    strokeColor: "#0000FF",//original color
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3
});
}
});
```

But you have to make it false again when you are start drawing a new path.

Comment: Check out the answer  of Charlie H. It is more clean. Plus thanks for you contribution.